# Como fazer com objetos em uma página a determinada largura se agrupem na vertical?

Tags: html, css

Galera, estou alinhado algumas `div` como colunas dentro de outra que serve como container. O que eu queria saber é como faço para que em determinada largura da própria `div` ou da página elas se agrupem uma encima da outra em um fluxo vertical?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Layout Responsivo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" class="clearfix">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <div class="logo">
                logo
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                menu
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="col" style="background: red;">

            </div>
            <div class="col" style="background: yellow;">

            </div>
            <div class="col" style="background: cyan;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
   *zoom: 1;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 900px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: #876;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3.6em;
    background-color: #2C82C9;
}

.logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: transparent;
}

.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: #456;
}

/*Content*/

.content{

    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 88%;
    height: 400px;

    /*...*/
    background-color: #546;
}

.col{
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código que você já possui, ou as tentativas que você fez que não deu certo.

Comment: Quais divs quer alinhar verticalmente? O `.header` e o `.content`?

Comment: @SamirBraga essas tres com a  `class=col`

Comment: Agrupar uma em cima da outra, você quer dizer sobrepor as divs? E sobrepor em fluxo vertical? Não entendi muito bem o que você quer...

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes sobrepor não. Quero que quando chegar a um determinado tamanho da janela do broswer, por exemplo, elas deixem de está alinhadas e fiquem umas abaixo das outras. Mas o problema já foi resolvido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o *Media Querie* do css:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .col {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Com o `max-width` você define a largura máxima, quando a largurada página for menor que essa, o que tiver dentro do querie irá ser chamado.

### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9phswk1k/)

Comment: Boa! Muito obrigado pela solução. Até mais

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar uma `media-query`

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .col{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por algum motivo de magia negra seu estilo não funcionou, msm assim obrigado pela força. abs